# Color Picker for AEM Component

Tags: extjs, aem

I'm trying to add a color picker to my AEM component, so users can set the color in the component dialog.  previously it was just a select list with text options...

```
<selectList  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Color" name="./color1" type="select" xtype="selection" options="/etc/designs/my-project/colors.json" />
```

I would like to use [ColorMenu](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.menu.ColorMenu) or [ColorPalette](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.ColorPalette) After some trial and error, I have the following ColorPalette in the component dialog...

```
<colorMenu jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Color" xtype="colorpalette" name="./color2" colors="" plugins="customColorPlugin"/>
```

The `customColorPlugin` function sets the colors array. The UI kind-of works and the palette has the colors to choose from. 
[image]

But I cannot figure out how to handle the click event to place the selected color into my AEM component properties.

I get the following JS Console Error when the dialog is opened

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   CQ.Ext.layout.AnchorLayout.CQ.Ext.extend.onLayout 
>   CQ.Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.CQ.Ext.extend.layout 
>   CQ.Ext.layout.ContainerLayout.CQ.Ext.extend.runLayout

And I get this when I click on a color

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of null 
>   CQ.Ext.ColorPalette.CQ.Ext.extend.select 
>   CQ.Ext.ColorPalette.CQ.Ext.extend.handleClick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'addClass' of null` occurs when hex codes for colors supplied by your plugin is in **lowercase** , it displays the colours alright but breaks on click. Just convert them to uppercase and it should work. You can also check out the [colorfield](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.ColorField) xtype.

Comment: Given the dialog.xml widgets, I need to convert the HEX to a class name. I have a change function the runs when the colorfield is changed. but how would I update a different widget (hidden textfield)? '<colorField jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Color" xtype="LSAColorField" allowBlank="false" name="./color2" colors=""/>
<clrClassName jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" name="./color_class_2" value="" xtype="textfield" hidden="true"/>'

Comment: If the clrClassName is a sibling of the colorfield , in the selection change get reference to color field and use next sibling() method to get the hidden field. Then use setValue() method on it to update the class name